# Using Labels in NASM

Tags: assembly, linked-list, x86, label, nasm

Using NASM.  I want to be able to leave a label address inline.

```
;
_Plus:      
DB 1, "+"
do_PLUS:     
POP EDX
ADD EDX , ESP     
MOV EDX , ESP
;
_COLON:
do_PLUS <---------- ** ERROR ** I want the address here 
PUSH $
;
```

> .asm:37: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
> .asm:37: error: label 'do_PLUS' inconsistently redefined
> .asm:30: info: label 'do_PLUS' originally defined here

See above example

Comment: You "want the address here" of *what*?  You already defined `do_PLUS` 5 lines previous to that.

Comment: I want to put the address of do_PLUS at that location.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Simple answer: Use a unique label name. Can be a local label (dot prefix), or if you're in a multi-line macro a macro-local label (two percent signs prefix), or in a context a context-local label (one percent sign then one dollar sign).

Comment: Is this what you are recommending? 
_Plus:      
DB 1, "+"
.do_PLUS:     
POP EDX
...
_COLON:
do_PLUS
DB 5
 warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]

Comment: This will make up a linked list.  The address(s) will be stored in a list.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> _COLON:
>   do_PLUS <---------- ** ERROR ** I want the address here 
>   PUSH $
> ```

> I want to put the address of do_PLUS at that location

Storing that address is just a matter of using `DD`:

```
_COLON:
  DD do_PLUS
  PUSH $
```

---

> ```
> POP EDX
> ADD EDX , ESP     
> MOV EDX , ESP
> ```

The fact that you're showing us this nonsensical code does not help in determining what it is that you hope to accomplish...

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question with an answer that works.  FYI, familiar with FORTH?  I am building a Forth OS.  It is based on threaded code.  You load the address of the next operation:   It is truly not nonsensical.  
   112                                  ;
   113                                  Forth_Thread:
   114 000000DB [29000000]              DD do_PUSH1 
   115 000000DF [67000000]              DD do_Double
   116 000000E3 [3E000000]              DD do_PLUS
   117 000000E7 [D9000000]              DD do_Endless
   118                                  ;